# php SOAP webservice failing to send an acknowledgement (ack) response to Salesforce

Tags: soap, workflowoutboundmessage, php

I am trying to set up a very simple webservice to consume salesforce outbound messages using php SoapServer class.

The salesforce outbound messages are being successfully received by the notifications method in the code below.

```
class mySoapHandler {

  public function notifications(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    error_log('notifications args: '.print_r($args,1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);
    return self::_respond('true');
  }

  private function _respond($tf){
    $ACK = <<<ACK
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
                    <Ack xsi:type="xsd:boolean">$tf</Ack>
                </notificationsResponse>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
ACK;
    return $ACK;
  }
}

try {
  $server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => 'https://website.com/services/SoapService.php'));
  $server->setClass('mySoapHandler');
  $server->handle();
}
catch(SOAPFault $e) {
  error_log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);
}
```

What is not working is the respond acknowledgement. It throws this error on the salesforce side: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.lang.String -> class java.lang.Boolean)

Does anyone know what might be causing this "Bad types" error?

The element schema is at the bottom of this page here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_wsdl.htm#i1473596

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml namespace on your `notificationsResponse` element is wrong it should be `http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound` but you have `https://website.com/outbound`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the delivery failure problem.

Comment: well it certainly doesn't have to be the only problem. can you get a capture of what the actual http request/responses look like.

Comment: is it possible that the SoapServer class is trying to wrap its own soap envelope around the response you provided.

Comment: I actually don't have access to the salesforce side of things, so I probably won't be able to get that in a hurry, but will try.

Comment: you only need access to the host where your code is running to get a capture of the req/res. You can also just use curl or SoapUI to send a request to your server and see the response.

Comment: the docs certainly imply that SoapServer is providing an envelope, so you shouldn't be including all the soap stuff in your response. easy to confirm by making a local request to your server.

Comment: Oh ok, the xml response looks to be fine. No extra tags being wrapped, just what's defined the heredoc syntax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7914/discussion-between-superfell-and-user1814739)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post working php code in case it might help somebody:

```
try {
  $server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => 'https://website.com/services/SFService.php'));
  $server->setClass('SoapHandler');
  $server->handle();
}
catch(SOAPFault $e) {
  error_log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);
}

class SoapHandler {
  public function notifications(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    error_log(print_r($args,1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);
    $response = '<Ack>true</Ack>';
    $response = new SoapVar($response,XSD_ANYXML);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

superfell was correct that the SoapServer class was wrapping its own soap envelope around the response, which is not very clear in the php manual.